# Time Series clustering: Changing warping window for Dynamic time warping

Tags: time-series, clustering, dynamic-time-warping

I'm working on the same type of data and i want to classify the times series to find clear pattern of use. My data is collected from clients of a telecom company, and we want to detect pattern of the amount of data consumed by clients with their wifi box. So each client have a time series of how much data he consumed each 6minutes (I resampled it to hours). I also applied DTW with KmeansTimeSeries using `tslearn`:

```
km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters = cluster_count, metric="dtw", verbose=1)
labels = km.fit_predict(mySeries)
```

My question is i want to change the warping window for DTW in python, and i'm pretty sure it's easy think to do, but i just coudn't find a way to do it. I also want to find the best window parameter for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you with the "I also want to find the best window parameter for my case."
part of your question.
Paper [a] explains how to do it.

[a]     Hoang Anh Dau, Diego Furtado Silva, François Petitjean, Germain Forestier, Anthony J. Bagnall, Abdullah Mueen, Eamonn J. Keogh:
Optimizing dynamic time warping's window width for time series data mining applications. Data Min. Knowl. Discov. 32(4): 1074-1120 (2018)

Comment: Thank you very much